# How to open parallel terminals and call same shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, terminal, gnome

I would like to open X gnome terminal and in this terminals open parallel shell script, which are same for all terminals.
I create one shell script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

for ou in 11 33 34 35 36 37 39 41 42
do

cd /home/filip/Desktop/Analyza\ NIFTY\ and\ CNVs/NIFTY\ pooling008/raw\ data/binar/$ou  

gnome-terminal  
 
sh vypis_s_prazdnymi_ready-rozdeleni_do_binu.sh > "$ou"_pool008.tsv 

done
```

I am calling another shell script with name vypis_s_......., but in this script are awk and R code, I think it is not problem, but there is export function and after that I receive the error log for it like:

> vypis_s_prazdnymi_ready-rozdeleni_do_binu.sh: 12: export: 1: bad variable name

I would like only this, open the terminals (number of terminals depend on loop) and for each terminal go to specific folder where is documents and same shell script. I would like to call it for all terminals in same time.

Comment: Your problem is probably in the `vypis_s_prazdnymi_ready-rozdeleni_do_binu.sh` script... and you may avoid interpolating the file name with quotes and replacing `"$ou"_pool008.tsv`by `${ou}_pool008.tsv`

Comment: And per the error message your script is probably trying to do an `export 1=...` which is not allowed, an env var should start by a letter.

Comment: I reapired that by calling function... Not to use sh but bash...But after that I found another problem, it is not parallel. So I have to use command parallel :-(

Comment: Indeed, I had a doubt on the real parallel need so I didn't talk about it. Is there still something needing an answer here or could the question be tagged closed ?